# Is it possible to mount a single LVM partition on a different machine?

Tags: ubuntu, mount, lvm

I had an LVM volume group `ubuntu-vg` created backed by three physical disk partitions, e.g., `sda1`, `sdb1`, and `sdc1`. One of these (`sda`) three disks failed, leaving me with a broken volume group. The logical partition `ubuntu-lv` had `ext4` file-system on it, and used to span across all three disks of the volume group. Is it possible to mount `sdb1` and `sdc1` separately on a different Ubuntu machine?

When I tried mounting `sdb1` on a different machine, it fails with the following error message:

```
# mount /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv sdb1
mount: /media/myuser/sdb1: can't read superblock on /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv.
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, when a single normal filesystem is broken up into three pieces, it will not be possible to mount any of the three pieces (except *maybe* the first one) in the normal way while the pieces are separated. The fact that your filesystem is housed on a LVM logical volume does not change this fact.

You could move both remaining disks together to a second Linux system (doesn't have to be Ubuntu) and if you had any logical volumes (LVs for short) that are physically located on only those two disks, you should be able to access them normally... assuming that the name of the LVM volume group does not conflict with an existing volume group in the second system.

To view the status of your LVs, run `sudo lvs -o +lv_health_status`. If you see the word `partial` with a LV (or a `p` in the 9th character of the `Attr` column), the LV has at least one part missing.

With `sudo vgchange -ay --activationmode partial`, you could get your `ubuntu-lv` activated, but with the part that was located on the missing `sda1` still unreadable. That would allow you to run file recovery tools like [PhotoRec](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) on the LV with parts missing, allowing you to try and recover files from the remaining parts of the LV.

Comment: Surprisingly, `Attr` says `-wi-------` for the broken LV.

Comment: Well, that indicates the LV has not been activated at all: an intact, active LV would show `-wi-a-----` while not mounted, or `-wi-ao----` when mounted.